# List all Requests for a given user

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-requests, facebook-invite

In the game I'm currently developing, we would like to have an inbox listing all pending [Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/ios-tutorial/#requests_step1) that the friends have sent to the currently logged in user. I know how to get some basic information out of the Graph API, but I'm lost on this one as I can't find any resources on how to do what I have just described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all requests by a GET request **/me/apprequests** with a game type application with a valid access token.

You can get reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/